# Error trying to set up user MFA Preferences

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I'm using the AWS CLI to enable a MFA user pool with only TOTP MFA (no SMS).

**aws cognito-idp set-user-pool-mfa-config --user-pool-id xxxx_xxxx --mfa-configuration OPTIONAL --software-token-mfa-configuration Enabled=true**

```
{
    "SoftwareTokenMfaConfiguration": {
        "Enabled": true
    },
    "MfaConfiguration": "OPTIONAL"
}
```

Seems okay, right?
But when I try to set up an user preference I keep getting this error:

***An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminSetUserMFAPreference operation: User has not set up software token mfa***

Command:
**aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-mfa-preference --user-pool-id xxxx_xxxx --username username@email.com --software-token-mfa-settings Enabled=true**

Tryin to use admin-set-user-preference also doesn't work:
**aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-settings --user-pool-id us-xxxx-xxxx--username username@email.com --mfa-option DeliveryMedium=EMAIL**

***An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminSetUserSettings operation: Only phone_number attribute is currently supported as a MFA option.***

What am I missing? Does it need an extra configuration not mentioned anywhere in documentation?

---

## Solution:

First you need to get the ACCESS_TOKEN for the user and proceed to start the TOTP process:

> aws cognito-idp associate-software-token --access-token ACCESS_TOKEN

(this will generate a unique code that you could use in Google Authenticator)

With the TOTP code retrieved from the Authenticator app run:

> aws cognito-idp verify-software-token --access-token ACCESS_TOKEN --user-code USER_CODE

With the successfull message from the previous command you can change the user preference:

> aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-mfa-preference --user-pool-id xxxxx --username xxxxxxx --software-token-mfa-settings Enabled=True,PreferredMfa=True

Comment: I'm stuck on this too; any updates?

Comment: Hi @NitsanAvni I've updated the original question with the solution

Comment: great stuff! thanks a lot

Comment: I'm just trying to disable the MFA for a specific user, why do i need to set up the TOTP?

Comment: @LucianoJr can you create an answer and past your solution in there and accept your answer to mark this question answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution:

First you need to get the ACCESS_TOKEN for the user and proceed to start the TOTP process:

> aws cognito-idp associate-software-token --access-token ACCESS_TOKEN

(this will generate a unique code that you could use in Google Authenticator)

With the TOTP code retrieved from the Authenticator app run:

> aws cognito-idp verify-software-token --access-token ACCESS_TOKEN --user-code USER_CODE

With the successfull message from the previous command you can change the user preference:

> aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-mfa-preference --user-pool-id xxxxx --username xxxxxxx --software-token-mfa-settings Enabled=True,PreferredMfa=True

Answer (score 0):

To setup the TOTP for user you have to call the AWS Cognito APIs in the following order

1. [Associate Software Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#associateSoftwareToken-property)
2. [Verify Software Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#verifySoftwareToken-property)
3. [Set User MFA Preference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#setUserMFAPreference-property)

The associate software token will give you an `SecretCode` which you will convert to a QR either so that user can scan it with an authenticator app. Then you will call the verify software token and pass it the code generated by the authenticator app. And finally you will enable the MFA by calling the set user preference API. And voila.