# AWS Cognito TOTP MFA setup NotAuthorizedException Invalid Access Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to setup an optional TOTP MFA for one user in my Cognito user pool but running into an issue -

My pool is setup with:

- MFA enforcement: Optional MFA
- MFA methods: Authenticator apps

If I try to update my Uses MFA configuration to "MFA active" in the AWS Console I get the following error:

```
[InvalidParameterException] Errors were encountered during MFA configuration update for user "xxxxxx". 
Please review the errors and retry.
InvalidParameterException (Request ID: xxxxxx)
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72468338) with the JWT Access Token I get back from Cognito when I login as this user:

```
aws cognito-idp associate-software-token --access-token [JWT_TOKEN]
```

But getting this error:

```
An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the AssociateSoftwareToken operation: Invalid Access Token
```

However if I use the same Access Token to retreive the user info from Cognito, it works ok:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://[SUBDOMAIN].auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [JWT_TOKEN]'
```

Response:

```
{"sub":"xxxx","email_verified":"true","email":"xxxxx","username":"xxxxx"}
```

Am I missing a parameter in my `associate-software-token` request? Odd that the AccessToken is valid when getting user info but invalid for MFA setup. Thanks!